# Apple TV play media stored on Airport Extreme hard drive?

Tags: airport, appletv, mediaplayer, plex

The current gen [Airport Extreme](http://www.apple.com/airport-extreme/) (802.11ac, you know... the tall white one) is capable of having a network accessible hard drive connected directly to it. Now that the new [Apple TV](http://www.apple.com/tv/) can run apps, can I use the Airport's connected hard drive as a media server and have the new Apple TV access its content directly? Maybe by running the [Plex app](https://plex.tv/appletv) (or similar)?

Comment: The Plex app is client software that receives its data from a Plex server.  Any generation Airport Extreme and Time Capsule just serve plain files.  What you will need is a standalone media player running on the (last generation) Apple TV.

Comment: Thanks, @EDP. So I need an app that can a) play media files, and b) see files on a network drive? Any suggestions of what to app to use on the Apple TV?

Comment: I'm not sure.  I don't have a new Apple TV.  Even so I'm thinking about 'nPlayer', 'Infuse' or 'VLC'.  Don't know whether these are available on Apple TV or not.  Please share your experiences if you test them.

Answer (score 1):

VLC should do the trick. I confirmed I can access the drive inside my Time Capsule using VLC on my Apple TV.

I imagine it will also access the files on a USB-connected drive. Not tested the latter though.

Comment: Does VLC have an Apple TV app?

Comment: It does. That's how I know it can access the drive inside my Time Capsule. I tried it. Note: only the latest model supports app installs.

Comment: Great…it wasn't there last time I looked.

Answer (score 0):

To use plex, you must install Plex Media Server from their  [website](http://plex.tv)  it takes care of all transcoding of content, and just takes it from connected drives.

Answer (score -3):

I'm using Infuse to play media from the Time Capsule and it is way better than the VLC.